# Change backgroundColor of textfield onFocus mui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

1. [image]

=======================================

I am trying to change the background color of input type date when calender is open but unable to figure out the way. here is the code

```
  dateInputRoot: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#EBEBEB',
    },

    '&:active': {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      borderColor: '#2EFF22',
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
  },
  dateInput: {
    border: 0,
  },

               <TextField
                  margin="dense"
                  type="date"
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={closeDate}
                  placeholder=""
                  fullWidth
                  style={{ paddingLeft: 0 }}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setCloseDate(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  className={classes.dateInputRoot}
                  InputProps={{
                    classes: { notchedOutline: classes.dateInput },
                  }}
                />
```

Problem is with active selector it changes the background only until I press the mouse button also no borderWidth is applying. i want to give background to white and some border when calendar is open.
Any help please

Comment: Have you tried the `focus` state?

Comment: Sometimes, your styling is correct but the order in which it is loaded differs. Hence, the default styling might be running.
There is one link : https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12192
This can help.

Comment: The style is working fine on onclick. but don't wanna apply that style when user click instead apply these styles when calendar is open....